# Obtain SharePoint users with an API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

When I create (or edit) Sharepoint List (any List) I can add columns, and specify the column type as "Person or Group"
[image]

So, then when I edit the list, in that column of a "Person" type, I choose user objects in a pop up.
[image]

What I now need to do is get the list of all those Users available for pick up (for a current site).  And I need to do it with the API.
I know how to use sharepoint API to get the list data, but need help understanding what to use as endpoint to get the user list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST API to get site's users.

[Users, groups, and roles REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#endpoint-uri-7)

It's working for both SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online.

Endpoint is: `https://your-sharepoint-webapp/_api/web/SiteUsers`

Result sample:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [{
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "https://your-sharepoint-webapp/_api/Web/GetUserById(1)",
                "uri": "https://your-sharepoint-webapp/_api/Web/GetUserById(1)",
                "type": "SP.User"
            },
            "Groups": {
                "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://your-sharepoint-webapp/_api/Web/GetUserById(1)/Groups"
            }
            },
            "Id": 1,
            "IsHiddenInUI": false,
            "LoginName": "i:0#.w|ad\\some-user",
            "Title": "some-user",
            "PrincipalType": 1,
            "Email": "some-user@company.local",
            "IsSiteAdmin": true,
            "UserId": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.UserIdInfo"
                },
            "NameId": "s-1-5-21-111111111-22222222222-33333333333-4444",
            "NameIdIssuer": "urn:office:idp:activedirectory"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  It works, but ... 
Unfortunately that does not give what I am looking for.
Your URL gives me the list of those who can access the site.
This is not the list I am looking for.  Colum type "Persson" gives a list of .. it could be Active Directory (if connected) or a specialty sharepoint created list of user objects, etc... (i our case it is active directory, I think).   Those people may not have the permission to even see the List, but they can still be chosen as a contact in a list.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the REST API only returns the users for the current site. You have others options : using the API for User Profile Service https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn790354(v=office.15) or try to mimic the people picker https://dattabase.com/blog/sharepoint-people-picker-rest-api